# Как запоминать данные между сеансами

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qcombobox, qsettings

Делаю *GUI* в *PyQt5*. Стоит задача сделать выпадающее меню с запоминанием данных (что выбрал в первый запуск приложения - выводится в следующие разы).

Выходит исключение:

> TypeError index 0 has type 'numpy.float64' but 'str' is expected.

Сам код:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel,
    QComboBox, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QWidget):
    

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        items = np.array(["Вариант 1", "Вариант 2",
             "Вариант 3", "Вариант 4", 
             "Вариант 5", "Вариант 6"])
        
        items = np.loadtxt('items.txt')
        print(items)
            
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)

        combo = QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItems(items)

        combo.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl.move(50, 150)

        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('KeyVoice')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        self.show()

    def onActivated(self, items):
        np.savetxt('items.txt', items, fmt='%d')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Как можно исправить ошибку и какие еще есть замечания по поводу кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы запомнить свои настройки (размеры и положения окон, параметры и т. д.)
между сеансами, вам надо изучить класс [**QSettings**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details).

Класс [**QSettings**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) предоставляет постоянные независимые от платформы настройки приложения.

Как вариант, это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
def restore(settings):
    finfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(settings.fileName())

    if finfo.exists() and finfo.isFile():
        for w in QtWidgets.qApp.allWidgets():
            mo = w.metaObject()
            if w.objectName() != "":
                for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                    name = mo.property(i).name()
                    val = settings.value(
                        "{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name),
                        w.property(name),
                        type=type(w.property(name)),                   
                    )
                    w.setProperty(name, val)

def save(settings):
    for w in QtWidgets.qApp.allWidgets():
        mo = w.metaObject()
        if w.objectName() != "":
            for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                name = mo.property(i).name()
                settings.setValue("{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class Example(QWidget):
# !!! +++
    settings = QtCore.QSettings("g1450561.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)    # !!! +++
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('KeyVoice')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.png'))        
        
        self.items = [
            "Вариант 1", "Вариант 2",
            "Вариант 3", "Вариант 4", 
            "Вариант 5", "Вариант 6"
        ]
        
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")                                # !!! +++
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.items)        
        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        
        restore(self.settings)                                                 # !!! +++

        self.label.setText(self.items[self.comboBox.currentIndex()])
        
    def onActivated(self, item):
        self.label.setText(item)
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):                                               # +++
        save(self.settings)                                                    # !!! +++
        QtWidgets.QWidget.closeEvent(self, event)                              # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]